# Detach an entity from a JPA persistence context (JPA 2.0 / Hibernate / EJB 3 / J2EE 6)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

I wrote a stateless EJB method allowing to get an entity in "read-only" mode.

The way to do this is to get the entity with the EntityManager then detach it (using the JPA 2.0 EntityManager).

My code is the following:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public T getEntity(int entityId, Class<T> specificClass, boolean readOnly) throws Exception{
  try{
    T entity = (T)entityManager.find(specificClass, entityId);
    if (readOnly){
      entityManager.detach(entity);
    }
    return entity;
  }catch (Exception e){
    logger.error("", e);
    throw e; 
  }
}
```

Getting the entity works fine, but the call to the `detach` method returns the following error:

```
GRAVE: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.detach(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.detach(EntityManagerWrapper.java:973)
    at com.mycomp.dal.MyEJB.getEntity(MyEJB.java:37)
```

I can't get more information and don't understand what the problem is...

Could somebody help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using JPA 2.0 with the incorrect version of Hibernate, which doesn't implement the JPA 2.0 spec. The exception tells that the `EntityManagerImpl` doesn't have the required method.

I suggest upgrading hibernate to 3.5, which is a JPA 2.0 implementation.

Comment: Thanks!
Just updated my Hibernate JARs to 3.5.0 CR2 and it works great.

Comment: Is the detach operation recursive (i.e. in cascade) ?

Comment: @Guido - yes, if you have cascadeType=DETACH

Answer (score 1):

You can detach all entities with clear but detaching just one entity is not in the JPA 2.0.
http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

You probably had hibernate impl in your build path, and another implementation on your application server (EclipseLink? or old hibernate version)...

The `entityManager.detach(...)` is in Hibernate but not in JPA so you need the hibernate impl on your application server to use this function...

Comment: The answer from Bozho resolved my problem.
Detach a single entity works FINE in JPA 2.0 (J2EE 6)